# Sentry: Ignore Exceptions which happen between 4 and 5 o'clock

Tags: sentry

Between 4 and 5 o'clock a remote system is regularly down.

This means some cron jobs produce exceptions.

Is there a way to ignore these exceptions.

But exceptions before or after that time period are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible with Sentry.

If you want you can watch this GitHub Sentry issue: [Mute whole projects in case of maintenance downtime #1517](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/1517).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a workaround for that;

```
Sentry.init(options -> {
                    options.setBeforeSend((event, hint) -> {
                        if (time is between 4-5 o-clock) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return event;
                    });
                }
);
```